# MatChipList tab navigation

Tags: angular-material

I have a mat-form-field that contains a chip list and another one that contains any other kind of input. I want to be able to navigate away from the chip list into the input field and into the following mat-form-fields but it seems like this behaviour is not supported. Does anyone have a work around for this to be able to navigate this components with tab?

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <input placeholder="Another unrelated field" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixswwc?file=app/chips-input-example.html

Comment: Tab does leave the chip list - but goes into the input. You can use `tabIndex="-1"` on either `<mat-chip-list>` or `<input>` and tab will go to the other component instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The infinite loop of focus happens because the `<input>` is inside of the `<mat-chip-list>`

It could be solved by doing the following

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList>
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    
  </mat-chip-list>
<input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <input placeholder="Another unrelated field" matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: what to do in this case? I am facing the same issue

Comment: @Hope I edited my answer to be more explicit.